# Problem 2-37(a) Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

2-37(a) Let $f: \Bbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \Bbb{R}$ be a continuously differentiable function. Show that $f$ is not $1$-$1$.

*Hint*: If for example, $D_1f(x,y) \neq 0$ for all $(x,y)$ in some open set $A$, consider $g:A \rightarrow \Bbb{R}^2$ defined by $g(x,y)=(f(x,y),y)$.

**My Attempt:**

For each $y \in \Bbb{R}$, define $ h_y:\Bbb{R} \rightarrow \Bbb{R}$ s.t. $h_y(x)= f(x,y)$. $\therefore D_1f(x,y)=h_y'(x)$. If $D_1f(x_1,y_1)= 0$ for some $(x_1,y_1)$, $\implies h_{y_1}'(x_1)=0 \implies h_{y_1}$ is not $1$-$1$ i.e. there exist $x_2,x_3 \in \Bbb{R}$ s.t. $h_{y_1}(x_2)=h_{y_1}(x_3) \implies f(x_2,y_1)=f(x_3,y_1)$. Thus $D_1f(x,y)$ must be nonzero for all $(x,y)$ in some open set $A$ if it is $1$-$1$.

Assume $D_1f(x,y) \neq 0$ for all $(x,y)$ in some open set $A$. consider $g:A \rightarrow \Bbb{R}^2$ defined by $g(x,y)=(f(x,y),y)$. $g$ is continuously differentiable. Now $$\det\, g'(x,y)=\det\,
\begin{pmatrix} 
D_1f(x,y) & D_2f(x,y) \\
 \frac{\partial y} {\partial x}   & \frac{\partial y} {\partial y}
\end{pmatrix} \neq 0$$ $\therefore g^{-1}$ exists and is differentiable and $(g^{-1})'(x,y)=[g'(g^{-1}(x,y))]^{-1}$

Note: $f(g^{-1}(x,y))=x$

Now $$ [g'(g^{-1}(x,y))]^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix} 
 \frac{\partial f(g^{-1}(x,y)) } {\partial x}& \frac{\partial f(g^{-1}(x,y)) } {\partial y}\\
\frac{\partial y} {\partial x}& \frac{\partial y} {\partial y}
\end{pmatrix}^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix} 
 1& 0\\
0&1
\end{pmatrix}$$
Thus $(g^{-1})'$ is the identity matrix

I don't know how to proceed. Can someone give a **hint**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your first paragraph is wrong: Consider $h_y(x)=x^3$.

However, if both partial derivatives vanish on an open set, you conclude that the function must be constant on that open set. If not, one partial must be nonzero somewhere, and hence by continuity, must be nonzero an open set, say $A$.

I don't understand where you get your computation that $g'(g^{-1}(x,y))$ is the identity matrix. But the point is, as you say, that you have a *local* inverse $g^{-1}$ of $g$ and that $f(g^{-1}(x,y)) = x$ for all $(x,y)$ in a suitable open set. Fixing $x$ and varying $y$ in open set gives you infinitely many points that $f$ maps to a single point.

Comment: You are right. My first paragraph is wrong.